# How to to save int in UIViewController

Tags: ios, int

The question is very simple.

```
//in viewDidLoad I get int;
int i = self.tabViewController.tabs.count; //from other viewController
```

The variable "i" will change, because I'll add tab(s) and thus the tab count will change.
The next time I will get the variable "i" it might be changed depending on how many tabs were added.
How can I save the initial value of the variable "i" as saved in "viewDidLoad"?

Comment: Make "i" a property of your class. Then you can say `self.i = self.tabViewController.tabs.count`. But also remember if you do it this way, when you access again `self.i` it will have the **original** value. Not the modified one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to access two pieces of information. The first is the value of self.tabViewController.tabs.count in the viewDidLoad method and the second is the the value of self.tabViewController.tabs.count at some later point in time. Just redefine "i" as the value of self.tabViewController.tabs.count in viewDidLoad and just access self.tabViewController.tabs.count directly whenever you need the current tab count at any later point in time.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this:

Define a class property to keep track of the initial tab index:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger initialTabIndex;
```

You can retrieve the current tab index and save it:

```
self.initialTabIndex = self.tabViewController.selectedIndex;
```

When needed you can switch back to this index:

```
self.tabViewController.selectedIndex = self.initialTabIndex;
```